# Load the data into html table from json formatted variable

Tags: javascript, python, html

I need to load json dump data returning from a python script into my html table, not sure what am i doing wrong as i am relative new to html and doing this for a POC. I'm unable to load the data into a html table. seeking your help.

```
Python Code
def read_data_from_sql(sqlserverinst,uname,psswd,dbname,url,regime,jurisdiction):
    output=[]
    conn = pymssql.connect(sqlserverinst, uname, psswd, dbname)
    cursor = conn.cursor(as_dict=True)
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM [reg_content_extracted_url_browsed]')
    for row in cursor:
    output.append({'url_id': row['url_id'],'url': row['url'],'regime': row['regime'],'jurisdiction': row['jurisdiction']})
    # flat_list = [item for sublist in output for item in sublist]
    conn.close()
    print(json.dumps(output))
    return json.dumps(output)
```

Output format : [{"url_id": 1, "url": "www.google.com", "regime": "FATCA", "jurisdiction": "SG"}]

```
HTML Table layout
<div class="content-large">Successful Browsed URL(s)
    
    <!-- <style>
        table, th, td {
        border:1px solid black;
        }
    </style> -->
    <table id="btable" style="width:100%">
        <tr style="color: white;">
          <th>url id ID</th>
          <th>url</th>
          <th>Regime</th>
          <th>Jurisdiction</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          
        </tr>            
    </table>
</div>

Script to populate json data
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script type=text/javascript>
$(function() {
  $('a#test').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    $.get('/datahomepage',
        function(data) {
            // alert(data);
            alert(data.length)
            // console.console.log("hheh"); 
            var tr;
            for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++){

                alert(data[i].url_id)
                tr = $('<tr/>');
                tr.append("<td>" + data[i].url_id+ "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + data[i].url+ "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + data[i].regime+ "</td>");
            $('btable').append(tr);
            }
            
    });
    // return false;
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: The keys User_Name , score and team which you are using in your JavaScript file are not returned as part of the data from your python script.  You need to ensure that the keys referenced are available

Comment: update the code.

Answer (score 0):

An obvious error is:

```
$('btable').append(tr);
```

which should be

```
$('#btable').append(tr);
```

Comment: I add # still not able to populate the html table. I tried the alert() methord to see what is returned from python function , which is correct json formatted string [{"url_id": 1, "url": "www.google.com", "regime": "FATCA", "jurisdiction": "SG"}]
However when i try to loop through it , i am getting undefined message.

Comment: so , i am able to solve this by parsing the string with JSON JSON.parse(data)